# Ruby Mechanize screen scraping help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a row in a table with a date. I want to scrape only the third row that have the date today.

This is my mechanize code. I am trying to select the colum row witch have the date today and its and its columns:

agent.page.search("//td").map(&:text).map(&:strip)

```
Output:
"11-02-2011", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0,00 DKK", "0,00", "0,00 DKK", 
"12-02-2011", "5", "5", "1", "4", "0", "0,00 DKK", "0,00", "0,00 DKK", 
"14-02-2011", "1", "3", "1", "1", "0", "0,00 DKK", ",00", "0,00 DKK",
"7", "9", "3", "6", "0", "0,00 DKK", "0,00", "0,00 DKK
```

"

I want to only scrape the third row that is the date today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than loop over the `<td>` tags using `'//td'`, search for the `<tr>` tags, grab only the third one, then loop over `'//td'`.

Mechanize uses Nokogiri internally, so here's how to do it in Nokogiri-ese:

```
html = <<EOT
<table>
<tr><td>11-02-2011</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0,00 DKK</td><td>0,00</td><td>0,00 DKK</td></tr>
<tr><td>12-02-2011</td><td>5</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0,00 DKK</td><td>0,00</td><td>0,00 DKK</td></tr>
<tr><td>14-02-2011</td><td>1</td><td>3</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0,00 DKK</td><td>,00</td><td>0,00 DKK</td></tr>
</table>
EOT

require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

pp doc.search('//tr')[2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }

>> ["14-02-2011", "1", "3", "1", "1", "0", "0,00 DKK", ",00", "0,00 DKK"]
```

Use the `.search('//tr')[2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }` appended to Mechanize's `agent.page`, like so:

```
agent.page.search('//tr')[2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }
```

It's been a while since I played with Mechanize, so it might also be `agent.page.parser...`.

---

EDIT:

> there will come more rows in the table. The row that i want to scrape is always the second last.

It's important to put that information into your original question. The more accurate your question, the more accurate our answers.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is that there will come more rows in the table. The row that i want to scrape is always the second last.

Comment: How do i grab the second last row :) ?

Comment: Have found the answer :) agent.page.search('//tr')[-2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }

Comment: @Rails beginner: "agent.page.search('//tr')[-2].search('td').map{ |n| n.text }". Yep. Very good!