# Ruby get tables from HTML

Tags: html, ruby, html-table

Is there a module in Ruby which gives me the tables stored within an HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a way to parse HTML to extract information from tables?

Have a look at [Nokogiri](http://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBkQFjAA&url=http://nokogiri.org/&ei=HUEcTtyCGYPtsgbpoZjyBg&usg=AFQjCNGGJXwnp2_8mv2Ut0iT7yW6FzfUtA&sig2=XU3B_weYge3x2nhNz4zIiQ). That works great for most cases.

Comment: i had already looked at it but couldn't find "get_tables"

Comment: That is true. It is much more low-level. You should use XPath expressions to select the elements you want to view.

Comment: so, no.         -------------------

Comment: i guess no is the correct answer.

Comment: I've been using Nokogiri for screen-scraping sites and it works really great. It is not that hard to master but if you are looking for a tool that understands HTML primitives directly then it might not fulfill your needs...

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) for screen scraping. Here is an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997877/ruby-mechanize-screen-scraping-help) of mine, where I am scraping a table.